# how to auto respond to powershell.exe untrusted publisher prompt

Tags: powershell

i have my own local custom cert i created and signed powershell scripts with. when the self-signed ps1 script I have executes on another windows system that is set execution-policy to "Allsigned" i will get the prompt below when running the line with powershell.exe, within a batch file..

powershell.exe -nologo -file "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test\test.ps1"

```
Do you want to run software from this untrusted publisher?

File C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test\test.ps1 is published by CN=get_test PowerShell and is not trusted on your system. Only run scripts
from trusted publishers.

[V] Never run  [D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [A] Always run  [?] Help

(default is "D"):
```

i can't run -bypass mode for powershell.exe so that is out of the question. so i'm trying to find a way to auto respond to this prompt with R. it looks as though the prompt is within powershell itself and NOT from the windows cmd line.  i tried echo'ing R within the batch file as

```
echo R|powershell.exe -nologo -file "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test\test.ps1"
```

but that still didn't work. i looked at the powershell.exe options and didn't see a way to respond via parameter other than setting -bypass mode which i am not able to do in the environment.

is there any known way to code a respond to this prompt from powershell.exe ?? or is it just not possible unless you can execute with -bypass mode? thanks

Comment: Install the appropriate certificate so the other computer trusts your code. "*setting -bypass mode which i am not able to do*" - make it so you can do that. If it's an administrative policy, it's almost certain to mean "don't bypass the code signing by any means" rather than "don't use the bypass parameter but if you can kludge a way around it, great!".

Comment: FYI the above poster did not say where to install the certificate.  The code signing certificate needs to be installed to Trusted Publishers in the computer certificate store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the script as follows on target computer:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass -c " . 'path_to_script.ps1';"
```

If you are not able to run still, then as john commented, your organization has strict policy in place to block Powershell script execution.

Group Policy example is described in http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/set-the-powershell-execution-policy-via-group-policy/

In such case, you need to sign your code which involves:

1. requesting a certificate with Extended Key Usage called codeSigning(1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3)
2. Importing the issued certificate into Trusted Publishers on target machines

You can start by reading https://www.darkoperator.com/blog/2013/3/5/powershell-basics-execution-policy-part-1.html

Comment: i just went with self signing via powershell with a cert i created using powershell, thanks for the insight. very helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you need to disable that security prompt as part of your script / CI pipeline, you can also execute the following before running your script:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force
# and then, for example:
venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
# or
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test\test.ps1
```